# Regular expression for cell formula to exclude units

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I would like to remove some texts from my string and leave only numbers (formula )

example

=(3m2*3m)*2/10worker

The idea is to write regular expression to leave only text and operators like "*" or "/" but remove all defined units like "m2" or "m3" (cubic meters) or "worker" from the string. I need this to write formulas in excel and then have possibility to know whats the meaning particular numbers in formula

I have got formula as follow :

```
Function xxx(cell As String, _
        Optional ByVal IsGlobal As Boolean = True, _
        Optional ByVal IsCaseSensitive As Boolean = True) As Variant

    'Declaring the object
    Dim objRegExp As Object

    'Initializing an Instance
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    'Setting the Properties
    objRegExp.Global = IsGlobal
    objRegExp.Pattern = "[a-zA-Z^0-9_,-]"
    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = Not IsCaseSensitive

    'Execute the Replace Method
    xxx = Evaluate(objRegExp.Replace(cell, ""))
End Function
```

and i wonder how to write regex for my purposes.

Comment: Try `m\d\b|[^0-9.*/()+-]+` to replace with an empty string. Or, `(\d)m\d\b|[^0-9.*/()+-]+` to replace with `$1`.

Comment: This m\d\b|[^0-9.*/()+-]+ expression work fine for me but i need a little update to use it also with decimal numbers  like =(0,3m2*3m)*2/10worker or   =(0.3m2*3m)*2/10worker (with "," or "."). By the way thanks a lot

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/FZRhez/1. `objRegExp.Pattern = "m\d\b|(\d*[,.]?\d+)|[^0-9.*/()+-]+"` and `objRegExp.Replace(cell, "$1")`

Comment: Very helpfull thanks a lot . Because i evalueate string to the function in Excel VBA i use WorksheetFunction.Substitute(string, ",", ".") to change commas to dots and then use your previous pattern - it helped . Thanks

Comment: See the answer with explanations below.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
objRegExp.Pattern = "m\d\b|(\d*[,.]?\d+)|[^0-9.*/()+-]+"
```

and then

```
objRegExp.Replace(cell, "$1")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FZRhez/1). To make sure the commas are parsed as decimal separators, replace them with a `.` (you may just use `s = Replace(s, ",", ".")`).

**Pattern details**

- `m\d\b` - `m` followed with a digit and a word boundary
- `|` - or
- `(\d*[,.]?\d+)` - Group 1 (referred to with `$1`): any 0+ digits, an optional `,` or `.`
- `|` - or
- `[^0-9.*/()+-]+` - 1 or more chars other than digits, `.`, `/`, `(`, `)`, `+` and `-`. Maybe you want to add a `,` here, add it after the `0-9`.